# AVMediaTypeAudio not working in ios 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, ios10, ios11

I am working on audio merge and it works fine on iOS 10 but not working on iOS 11.

How can I access the audio file path in iOS 11?

```
NSArray *path;
path = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
        [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
         NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",trackName,(i==0) ? 
        (_editRecoding) ? fileExtension : @".mp3" : ([trackName 
        isEqualToString:@"temp"]) ? @".mp3" : @""],
        nil];

AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL 
                          fileURLWithPathComponents:path] options:nil];


 NSLog(@"audioAsset : %@", audioAsset);
 NSLog(@"AVMediaTypeAudio : %@", [audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio]);
```

Output in iOS 10 :

```
 audioAsset : <AVURLAsset: 0x17422b480, URL = file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6E092FA1-BE2C-4ECC-897F-3599005F2936/Documents/temp.mp3>

 AVMediaTypeAudio : (
    "<AVAssetTrack: 0x170011fb0, trackID = 1, mediaType = soun>"
)
```

Output in iOS 11 :

```
audioAsset : <AVURLAsset: 0x1c4437ba0, URL = file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EC64309F-7E09-4DAE-B19C-2A8F160627C3/Documents/temp.mp3>

AVMediaTypeAudio : (
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can i access the audio path in ios 11?

There is no different method than you are already using it.
As per the [AVMediaType documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmediatype/1386140-audio) there is no api change for IOS11.

**Solution:**

I bet your IOS 11 version is 11.0.2, so you should upgrade to 11.0.3, they fixed this audio issue in this version, take a look on release note.

Apple’s iOS 11.0.3 release notes list fixes for two specific problems:

**1.**  Fixes an issue where audio and haptic feedback would not work on some iPhone 7 and iPhone 7 Plus devices

**2.**  Addresses an issue where touch input was unresponsive on some iPhone 6s displays because they were not services with genuine Apple parts

**and also before you update to latest first check what will be the new trouble i face after upgrade.**

> Prevention is better than cure

check this out [11.0.3 update](https://www.forbes.com/sites/gordonkelly/2017/10/17/apple-ios-11-0-3-problems-ios-11-problem-iphone-battery-life/#17e9ecffe336) after you decide what you should do.

Comment: which iPhone you have?

Comment: seems this problem still remain on lower device.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Latest IOS, iPhone 7plus